# Allow non-privileged users to suggest tag wiki content

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki, privileges

Currently a lot of tag wikis are empty, probably because there is very few people who has the privilege to change it and even fewer who want to take the time to create the content. And maybe non-privileged users have a lot of nice ideas, but these ideas will not be implemented because nobody who can edit the wikis know about the ideas.

How about a normal user can suggest content and it will have to be approved by a privileged user before it actually appears? Perhaps like the discussion page in Wikipedia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed with the advent of the new edit suggestion system, see [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

All registered users can suggest wiki edits.