# How to report annoying editing of my questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I have serious issue now with guy that edit my question and another questions that related to one of exist tag, I have no problem if that tag was right tag, or at least that tag has a description that make using that tag acceptable.

I have many question like:

[GlassFish Application Server Does Not Prompt for User Name and Password when Accessing Admin Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634152/how-to-re-enable-login-screen-after-cluster-activating-in-glassfish-2-1-1)

[Does Alfresco 3.4e CE support clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075102/is-alfresco-3-4e-ce-support-clustering)

[Alfresco Exception caused by MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry ... etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077694/alfresco-exception-caused-by-mysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-duplica)

All question tags edited, replacing [clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) with [cluster-computing](/questions/tagged/cluster-computing), I don't know why? and what will be better to use! I think clustering is better !

BTW, after I checked that tag, I note that all questions under that tag edited by same guy!
That guy btw has not real info too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cluster-computing

I don't have any problem of editing if that done correctly, but I post this question not for only a report that guy or tag, I need how to prevent that?, or at least how to report that? and if I'm in wrong or right about my rolling back !

And I "suggest" to make editing questions reputation requirement higher.

Comment: did you read the description of the clustering tag?: Clustering has 2 meanings; please use the tag [Computer-clustering ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) or [Data-clustering ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering), in addition to Clustering.

Comment: @örs yes, before and after this issue, and if clustering tag meaning don't use me why its exist, I thing "clustering" is best tag for my question, read my question and understand it, my issue not hardware to use Computer-clustering ! as example. my questions was in general while I'm clustering my applications. AND btw I want to focus on this issue not on cluster issue here.

Comment: [Breaking news: other people are at their liberty to edit your stuff.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

Comment: The `clustering tag` is ambiguous, the `cluster-computing` tag is a better fit. Also because this is a programming site it won't mean clustered computing hardware.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. I don't see how a user changing a tag in your questions is a "serious issue". You're over reacting, and don't even consider the possibility that you're wrong. Be nice(r).
2. `That guy btw has not real info too.` That guy has all the information he is **required** to have. There is no actual value in "real info", we don't judge users by the crap they write in their profile but by their contributions.
3. Posting a meta question is the correct way of reporting anything that annoys you, and getting feedback and solutions (if what you're reporting is an actual issue).
4. Never again target an individual user, instead target & report the behaviour.

You reverted the changes in all questions. That's ok, but then in one question you seem to have [an edit war going on](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8634152/revisions). That's unacceptable, from both of you. For your part, when you first noticed the retagging, you should have posted a meta question and ask if [clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) makes more sense than [cluster-computing](/questions/tagged/cluster-computing), and not assume that you are correct by default.

That said, I happen to believe that [cluster-computing](/questions/tagged/cluster-computing) is far better than [clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering), which is [kind of ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clustering/info).

Comment: 1. I re-edit /roll back his editing / 2. did you see his location, website, description of him ! if he is a professional man that makes him responsible why he put these info, for me I don't trust on who have like that to learn from him! / 3. I know, than you / 4. I'm not targeting an individual user (where that user name that I target!) & I put my links as example ! not more, to understand my question ! you need example and now you calling that targeting ! and do that again ! / If I must use `cluster-computing` why? I don't see any description about this tag !

Comment: Why you still thinking that I have a problem with someone individuality! and why you don't respect my opinion, I don't have a time to read all questions of him and all answers to know him, I can have an idea of that guy how to think what his field and etc, I don't go to farmer as example to answer me about radio-chemistry issue!

Comment: I don't have reputation to edit and add description, and at first I don't understand what he means, if he means `Computer Clustering` not that's my issue! and who have a time to search question and editing them, I think he has a time to add description about it !

Comment: @al case in point, your own description says "funny guy and like fun", which certainly from *this* question appears to be somewhat inaccurate?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar you don't need reputation to [suggest an edit to a tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/9228). It works exactly the same as any other suggested edit. [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78898/154171)

Comment: @AakashM I put that cuz sometime I put little fun things on my answers ! its good to draw smiles while another have a problem ! that what I believe in anyway., at least too i put about my experience too !

Comment: @JasonPlank OK, why I suggest ! maybe I thing to suggest editing, but adding, I think who add tag MUST add description too ! and I said, at first I need to understand what `cluster-computing` means, what I understand now about that its totally different from my question, why then I say all this !

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I can be nicer, when you don't attack me and for some reason seems you targeting me! I don't know why you just see that I'm attacking someone not 'general' question need answer ! , and btw, I waste my time with you now. I don't have time to repeat my words and describe it millions times.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I said `what I understand now about that its totally different from my question` & I don't accept to be in my question ! & stop insulting me, I don't accept that under no circumstances.

Comment: **Moderator Note** This _entire_ comment thread is going to vanish if this silly bickering ensues. There is no way I can prune the noise out of this while leaving a coherent conversation in place. Please agree to disagree, and stop the noise.

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect on point 4, since as far as I know you can't report someone that edited your question.

Comment: @Hasen You can raise a custom moderator flag to report the edit privately to moderators, or you can report the edit publicly in Meta.

Answer (score 21):

The [tag wiki of clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clustering/info) explains that

> Clustering has 2 meanings; please use the tag
>   [Computer-clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster)
>   or [Data-clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering) ,
>   in addition to Clustering. For data-clustering, giving sizes -- Ndata,
>   Ndimension, Ncluster -- will help people to give better answers.

[clustering](/questions/tagged/clustering) is an ambiguous tag, you shouldn't use it for new questions but instead use one of the two less ambiguous tags mentioned in the tag wiki.

The editor was just following the advice of the tag wiki, if you think the current tagging principle from that tag wiki could be improved, you should start a discusssion about this tag on meta.